# what was the first RFC to describe hypertext references?

Tags: html, href, rfc

The oldest one I can find is [RFC 2616](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt)...but I would've expected links to be described before 1999.

Comment: Just found a [paper from 1965](http://signallake.com/innovation/FileStructure65.pdf) that has the first reference to the term "hypertext".